# Why CMake option command should be ON or OFF?

Tags: cmake

According to the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html):

> Provides an option for the user to select as ON or OFF

However, I noticed that the command works with any other values.

My test script:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

option(MY_VAR "var description" OFF)

message("MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}")
if(MY_VAR)
    message("MY_VAR is not OFF/FALSE/0")
endif()
```

Results:

```
>cmake ..
or
>cmake -DMY_VAR=OFF ..

output:
MY_VAR=OFF
```

```
>cmake -DMY_VAR=ON ..
output:
MY_VAR=ON
MY_VAR is not OFF/FALSE/0
```

```
>cmake -DMY_VAR=FALSE ..
output:
MY_VAR=FALSE
```

```
>cmake -DMY_VAR=TRUE ..
output:
MY_VAR=TRUE
MY_VAR is not OFF/FALSE/0
```

```
>cmake -DMY_VAR=0 ..
output:
MY_VAR=0
```

```
>cmake -DMY_VAR=1 ..
output:
MY_VAR=1
MY_VAR is not OFF/FALSE/0
```

```
cmake -DMY_VAR=3 ..
output:
MY_VAR=3
MY_VAR is not OFF/FALSE/0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation for `option` command describes just a **convention** about possible values. By itself, the `option` does NOT check a value of the variable, so the variable could contain **any string**.

**Actual interpretation** of the variable is up to the `CMakeLists.txt` script.

Usually, options are checked with `if(VAR)` syntax, so they are interpreted according to the documentation for `if` [command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions):

> True if the constant is `1`, `ON`, `YES`, `TRUE`, `Y`, or a non-zero number. False if the constant is `0`, `OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `N`, `IGNORE`, `NOTFOUND`, the empty string, or ends in the suffix `-NOTFOUND`.

As you can see, the `if` command allows several values for an option to be True-interpreted, and several values to be False-interpreted. (There is no reason to use values with `-NOTFOUND` suffix: they are intended to be produced only by a command like `find_library`.)